# How to update table data with own encrypt function?

Tags: php, mysql

i got my own encrypt function, i need use UPDATE to encrypt my data in database

```
/* Insert Data from .csv file */
while (($data = fgetcsv($handle, 1000, ",")) !== FALSE) {
    $import = "INSERT INTO temp(productName, serial) VALUES('$productName', '$data[0]')";
    mysql_query($import);
}
fclose($handle);

/* Encrypt all the data in the table */
$update = "UPDATE temp SET productName = ".OwnEncryptFunction(productName, $key)." ,
           serial = ".OwnEncryptFunction(serial, $key)." ";
mysql_query($update);
```

after i insert all the data into table TEMP. i want to encrypt it wit my own function.
But it doesnt work????

i tried this before, it works but not for 10k++ data. took too long to insert:

```
while (($data = fgetcsv($handle, 1000, ",")) !== FALSE) {
    $import = "INSERT INTO temp(productName, serial) VALUES('".OwnEncryptFunction(&productName, $key)."', '".OwnEncryptFunction($data[0], $key)."')";
    mysql_query($import);
}
fclose($handle);
```

can any one help to solve??

Comment: Why don't you encrypt the product name and key **before** you insert it into a table? EDIT: Your first update query is going to update EVERY record with the same serial and key on each iteration of the while loop.

Comment: I suspect it is not the `INSERT`, that takes so long, but the encryption. That said, I strongly advise you to NOT use a homegrown encryption function. Google for a second opinion - maybe using "Schneier" as a search term.

Comment: because the name and serial was insert from .csv file..
i need to check the .csv file for duplicate data.. then insert to database to check with database again

Comment: @EugenRieck ya.. is the encrypt function took long time... i no choice to use homegrown encryption function, because of the security feature. if i no use the encrypt function, insert 100k++ data only less than 2 min.

Comment: I hope the data you're encrypting isn't anything you need to use for indexed searches, encrypting data on the DB is generally a real overkill except in the most extreme circumstances (e.g. credit card numbers)... and if your business case is considered that extreme, then a "homebrew" encryption is NOT the solution

Comment: @MarkBaker ya.. i know, just the security purpose need to encrypt the serial number for the product, incase the database been stolen or hijack?

Comment: Your homegrown security function is almost guaranteed to be much less secure, than a proven algorithm like AES or *fish. So it it not a security feature, but a less security feature. You may also find, that AES might be much faster than your algorithm.

Comment: @Eugen - simple answer, if OP can show us his OwnEncryptFunction() code, and we can asses it

Comment: What happens if there's already encrypted data in the temp table, that's going to get re-encrypted again and again?

Comment: @MarkBaker data all from .csv file.. all plain text..
after insert into database then encrypt it

Answer (score 0):

```
$update = "UPDATE temp SET productName = ".OwnEncryptFunction(productName, $key)." ,
       serial = ".OwnEncryptFunction(serial, $key)." ";
```

should be

```
$update = "UPDATE temp SET productName = ".OwnEncryptFunction($productName, $key)." ,
       serial = ".OwnEncryptFunction($serial, $key)." ";
```

?

Comment: not,this wont work~~
cos i get the productName and serial in the database.. not the $productName variable

Comment: Can't understand how you going to obtain this data in PHP.  If you want to update data direct in DB it will be much batter and faster to use stored procedures, if your DB supports this feature.